# WampServer issues after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, wamp

Since upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10, WampServer does not appear to be working (anything loaded in the browser is just a blank page), and even a fresh install does not cure the problem.

Under `Apache > Service > Install Service` it states:

```
Your port 80 is actually used by :

Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0

Cannot install the Apache service, please stop this application and try again.

Press Enter to exit...
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Offsite dupe [Can't use WAMP , port 80 is used by IIS 7.5](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9621592)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove IIS for WampSERVER?](http://superuser.com/questions/694800/how-to-remove-iis-for-wampserver)

Answer (score 22):

## Update: this seems to fix it permanently

1. Search for "Turn Windows features on or off" on the taskbar.
2. Under "Internet Information Services" deselect "World Wide Web Services" that Microsoft must turn on by default (takes port).
3. Reboot and WAMP came back up as before.

## Original solution

I can confirm the following fixed the problem:

Run `cmd` as Administrator, and enter: `iisreset /stop`

Then `Apache > Service > Install Service` will prompt you to press Enter to install as normal.

You may also need to install: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: True that was the problem for me as well. Which service can I disable or does `iisreset /stop` tell windows, not to restart it, on next boot?

Comment: @Armin This does seem to be a temporary fix. Please let me know if you find a permanent solution.

Comment: No, for me it seems to be permanently. I've rebooted and the port is open now.

Comment: @Armin I recently updated and had to do the above again :(

Comment: @Armin if you do get an issue, try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31726134/1094772

Answer (score 3):

**For Windows 10 Clean Install :**

If you have done clean installation of Windows 10, you may not have the **Word Wide Web Publishing Service**. In that case, simple WAMP/XAMPP installation should work fine.

If it doesn't, try installing **[Visual C++ Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)** and then re-install WAMP/XAMPP.

---

I was facing a similar problem with WAMP. In Windows 10 TP, the **Word Wide Web Publishing Service** comes pre-installed. This is related to IIS and you can remove it if you don't need it.

This blocks the port `80` making Apache act weirdly. You can do the following and try again.

- Go to Start, type in **services.msc**
- Scroll down in the Services window to find the **World Wide Web Publishing Service**.
- Right click on it and select **Stop**.

This should make port **80** free and restarting WAMP/XAMPP should get you up and running!

There are other ways to do fix this. http://praveenpuglia.com/make-wamp-work-on-windows-10-technical-preview/

Comment: Stopping (and disabling) the World Wide Web Publishing Service did it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After all the possible fixes that everybody has been mentioning in answers across the Internet, when it still didn't work, I figured out the missing step as:

`Running wampmanager.exe as Administrator`

It's so trivial - but leaving this answer for someone who was stuck like me.